# Preserve white space with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to highlight a text in the html string by using **Html Agility Pack**. I'm able to replace text with `<span class="highlight">`, but when I replace the text, the white space around the span tag is disappeared. For example, if the text is `"This text will be highlighted"`, it results as `"This text will be<span class='highlighted'>highlighted</span>"`, and white space gone before the span tag. This merges the words before and after the span with the span text. I simply do a recursive loop like that:

1. Get first child node
2. if the node is `#text`, than `node.InnerHtml = InnerText.Replace(search_term, span_code)`
3. if node has child node goto step 1
4. goto next sibling then go to step 1

Then I get the `InnerHtml` of the `HtmlDocument` as a result. I tried put space before `<span` and after `</span>`, but it removed them. I tried `HtmlDocument.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;` it didn't work either. I replaced all `"\n"` and `"\t"` chars with a space before creating `HtmlDocument` and after getting the html string, and it didn't affect neither.

How can I preserve the white space when using Html Agility Pack?

Comment: I've tried SGMLReader with XmlDocument. It keeps the white space but this time I had another problem. When I changed XmlNode's InnerText with <span> code, it encodes the "<" and ">" as "&lt;" amd "&gt;"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually `HtmlDocument.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;` did what I want. I realized now.